# arrays of string in C great confusion

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I think the whole concept of array and array of chars in C is quite confusing. Can you please tell me if my reasoning is correct?

I have an array of array of char like this

```
char * array[2];
for(i=0;i<2;i++)  {
        array[i]=calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    }
array[0] = strcpy(array[0], "blah");
array[1] = strcpy(array[1], "blahblah");
```

Now i want to put this array in the field of a struct (that field has type char**)
Can I go like this?

```
my_struct.array_field = &(array[0])
```

or is it a mistake?

Comment: `array` by itself is the pointer, so `my_struct.array_field = array` should be all you need.

Comment: Is it an oversight that `array[]` is dimensioned to 5, but you only allocate 2 buffers?

Comment: It's not a mistake, what did you want? I don't see why do you need the array if you will ultimately store the pointer in a struct field? You got me all confused and I thought the declaration was `char array[5];`. I have seen people putting the star next to the type name like `char* array[5];`, I put it next to the variable like `char *array[5];`, but it's my first time with someone who has not decided yet.

Comment: If you don't depend on having the memory zeroed, why do you accept the concomittant penalty? Also, `sizeof(char)` is always 1, guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign `array`

```
my_struct.array_field = array
```

`array` is converted to `char **`.

And note that `array` is not *an array of array of char*, it is an array of (five) pointers to `char`.

No need of

```
array[0] = strcpy(array[0], "blah");
array[1] = strcpy(array[0], "blahblah");
```

although no harm except confusion. You can copy strings by just changing it to

```
strcpy(array[0], "blah");
strcpy(array[0], "blahblah");
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I think I explained myself poorly, in the struct the field is defined `char** array_field` so is correct what @Marc B said? (and saying `my_struct.array_field = array` is the same as what I wrote before?)

Comment: Also the array is five elements and all elements are initializated (the blahs in the example are misleading I'm sorry) so can I use malloc instead of calloc since there is no need to "zeroing" them?

Comment: Edit your question then I will explain in detailed.